# Solution to ODE by using method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system:

$$x^{'''} + 3x^{''}+3x^{'} + x=e^{-t}$$

I read this [page](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx) and as I understood this method is sort of a trial and error one, and there is a list of proposed first attempts one should try to do. For this case, the guess according to the page would be some equation of the form $x(t)=ae^{-t}$.

I understand intuitively why is this the case, since the exponential functions can not appear "from nowhere" as differentiating it won't make it vanish. But this solution does not work, since the right hand side is always 0 for any $a$.

Also, the other suggestion where of the form: $a \sin(ct) + b \cos(ct)$, but of course this would never work in this case. Can you give me hint? Thank you.

Comment: It isn't a trial and error method - but the example you have is tricky in a couple of ways: first because there is a multiple root of the auxiliary equation $a^3+3a^2+3a+1=0$; and second because that root, $a=-1$, appears as the coefficient of $t$ in the exponent on the right-hand side. Both circumstances can be handled by going to an appropriate polynomial multiple of $e^{-t}$. The answer by @user577215664 might look like magic, but actually it is an example of a more general phenomenon and can be adapted to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^{'''} + 3x^{''}+3x^{'} + x=e^{-t}$$
First you have to solve the homogeneous DE.
$$x_h=e^{-t}(c_1+c_2t+c_3t^2)$$
$$\implies  x_p=at^3e^{-t}$$
Because $ce^{-t}$ is already a solution of the homogneous DE.

Note that you can rewrite the DE as:
$$(xe^{t})'''=1$$
$$z'''=1$$
Where $z=xe^t$. What will be your guess now for the particular solution ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell what do DE, $x_h$ and $x_p$ stand for?

Comment: DE = differential equation and $x_p$ stands for particular solution and $x_h$ for homogeneous solution @Sarah

Answer (score 1):

Since the characteristic equation is
$$z^3+3z^2+3z+1=(z+1)^3=0$$
the root $z=-1$, which is equal to the coefficient of the exponential on the right-hand side of the ODE, has multiplicity $3$ then your guess for a particular solution should be (as a reference see this [PAGE](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/higher/guessing/guessing.html)):
$$x(t)=t^3\cdot ae^{-t}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: $a=1/6$ does the job :)

Comment: @Sarah Well done!